# Docker Swarm with Azure errors with SoftTimeLimitExceeded

Tags: azure, docker, docker-swarm

I am having an issue creating a swarm in azure. I have a docker image in docker cloud. Following this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlpyiGAVBVg

Any one else get this and any ideas?

I try to create the swarm and get:

```
Creating AD application and Service Principal...
Created AD application '.............' and Service Principal 
'.............'
Testing login...
Deploying template in Azure...
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
... (more of that)
Deployment state: Succeeded
ERROR: SoftTimeLimitExceeded()
```